# Infer typescript function generic from param value

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
enum EventType {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second',
}

type First = {
  first: string;
  type: EventType.First;
};
 
type Second = {
  second: string;
  type: EventType.Second;
};

type Data = First | Second;

interface Options<T extends EventType = EventType> {
  matcher: (data: Extract<Data, { type: T }>) => boolean;
  type: T;
}

function foo(options: Options) {
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to achieve strict types on the `matcher` functions data param based on the value of `type`. For example with this usage:

```
foo({
  matcher: data => ..., // data has type First
  type: EventType.First,
});

foo({
  matcher: data => ..., // data has type Second
  type: EventType.Second,
});
```

My code doesn't achieve this, I think because it isn't clear where the generic `T` takes it's value. Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` must be made generic in order to allow `Options` to correctly infer the type:

```
enum EventType {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second',
}

type First = {
  first: string;
  type: EventType.First;
};
 
type Second = {
  second: string;
  type: EventType.Second;
};

type Data = First | Second;

interface Options<T extends EventType = EventType> {
  matcher: (data: Extract<Data, { type: T }>) => boolean;
  type: T;
}

function foo<E extends EventType>(options: Options<E>) {}

foo({
  matcher: data => true, // data has type First
  type: EventType.First,
});

foo({
  matcher: data => true, // data has type Second
  type: EventType.Second,
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN4FgBQUUAYgJYBOAzolALxQDkAZhdQwDQFEDKwAxgHsQAEzqNK-IcI4EAvgQKIMWMlRr08hKCzUAuKNXKkQAcwDcXKEsz74SNJgB0q6hfyy3URcqi9BIsU0iCX9hfUNjc0trYFsEEBRlRz8pNw8FfBioABEAQ0RcsRcaAB9fSRE3AmNEYHImXL4sAHl0RFIhSgAeZChgAA9akUpYeMTMMTsEh2AAPhxLCHy+AAs6-QAKYXzc20HyRsQuvIL2HCtlfV7ZWYBKOnmAIwEBABtgXJBPC5soZDSMkwwCA+O0hNoXl0YH1BqBhCMpuM5hsBG0OiBKPpWmCMVC7jh5PgCEwXhsglAlohVusoNsCg8rOQwMAzgB6Vm0nZQFa5EZZYrRS6jexJYqcdy3Kr4EkCMmLZZrcj6OmFWjzRBMllQdmc+k8vk+FIiQW-REzZIVYTi2SSoA)

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!